# code for Image Gradient plugin in Gimp 2.10.8

Tags: plugins, detection, edge-detection, gimp

I wrote a C++ code where I perform edge detection on color or gray images (ppm files).

My code works well but is not as good as a specific Gimp plugin, especially when detecting more faint edges (low luminosity gradient). The plugin I am referring to is under **Filters/Edge-Detect/Image Gradient** in Gimp 2.10.8. Mouse hover says "Compute gradient magnitude and/or direction by central differences".

Below I embedded a gray test image to compare the results (i.e. gradient intensity), although my work is in color as well. The test image consists of some 13 circular rings with various luminosities (constant for each ring). The difference in luminosity between two adjacent rings increases from 2 luminosity units (for the inner rings) to 30 luminosity units (for the outer rings) in the outward radial direction.

As expected, the detected gradient is small for the inner rings and higher for the outer rings. The problem is that my C++ code is less sensitive to small gradients than the Gimp plugin is, as can be seen from the other two images below.

Where can I find **the code for the Gimp Image Gradient plugin** so I can learn something from it? I am not interested in the other Gimp plugins for edge detection (I verified that they are not quite as good as the Image Gradient, *at least for my application*).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in the [GEGL package](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl)

File is [`operations/common/image-gradient.c`](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gegl/blob/master/operations/common/image-gradient.c)

Comment: A possible difference is that Gimp code works in linear space while if you are working with the plain RGB 8-bit values you are  working with Gamma corrected values. AFAIK GEGL does a lot of linear<->gamma data conversions. PS: Also AFAIK you can use GEGL as a command line module (but I have yet to figure out how). This could help you run tests faster.

Comment: I am not sure that gamma expansion or compression would explain my results. To check this, I built another test image, this time using EQUAL steps in luminosity: both the Gimp Image-Gradient edge detector and my code render all the 'edges' with equal intensity, which is the way it should be. I think you are right that there must be some nonlinearity issue here, but it must be applied on the gradient itself and not on the original local luminosity of the image (like in Gamma correction, AFAIK). Still looking at the Gimp code - not easy for me.